# Get last six months data calendar wise in mysql. If not data exists append zero to that data

Tags: mysql

I am having a table which consists of customers registered for a business. Any user may get registered in any month. Sometimes there will be no users in a particular month. The challenge is... to fetch last six months data in which, if there is no data for a particular month it should return zero with the month name(Even if there no entry with that month).

My Table structure is like this

bus_id  consumer_id  registration_date
1          1              2014-06-22 15:45:07
2          1              2014-06-22 15:45:09
3          1              2014-06-22 15:45:09
4          1              2014-06-22 15:45:11
11          2              2014-11-04 13:49:51
12          2              2014-11-04 14:06:22
13          2              2014-11-04 14:10:34
14          2              2014-11-04 14:11:27
15          2              2014-11-04 14:17:03
I wrote a query from stackoverflow advices

```
SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%b') AS month, 
                count((consumer_id)) AS count 
FROM consumer_mapper 
WHERE MONTH(registration_date) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
AND bus_id = 2 
GROUP BY MONTH(registration_date);
```

which returns output like this

```
month count
Sep    12
Nov    67
Dec    1
```

I want the below mentioned output

```
month   count
Jul     0
Aug     0
Sep     12
Oct     0
Nov     67
Dec     1
```

Kindly help me in solving this.

Comment: I think you should create a table with months and then left join it with consumer_mapper

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate of the one that was chosen.  The list of six months here is variable, depending on the current date.  Solutions that have a fixed list of values will not completely solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data for all months, but simply do not have data where `bus_id = 2`, then you can switch to using conditional aggregation.  This is simpler than the `left join` methods that use a list of all months, but it doesn't always work.  Whether it works depends on the data:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%b') AS month, 
       SUM(bus_id = 2) AS count 
FROM consumer_mapper 
WHERE MONTH(registration_date) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
GROUP BY MONTH(registration_date);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,  I must use bus_id = 2. As I'm filtering the consumer_id based on bus_id (i.e how many consumers for a business id).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff yes, it is simpler, but it, as you said, doesn't always work. And it has to work all the time, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @SasankAppalla . . . This query returns the counts only for `bus_id = 2`.  It is using all the data just to get the rows with zero counts (if they are available).